# NodeJS Multi-Class File Unexpected Behavior process.on('uncaughtException')

Tags: javascript, node.js, exception, file-io

I've narrowed my code down to a mcve. What I expect this to do is to get caught by the process.on('uncaughtException'), but instead it is being caught by the process.on('unhandledRejection'). Can someone let me know in detail why this is happening?

testDev.js

```
'use strict';

const DbConfigHandler = require ('./DbConfigHandler.js');

async function MainAwait( ) 
{
    var szConfigFilename;

    process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
        console.log(err.stack + "************");
        process.abort();
    });
    process.on('unhandledRejection', (err) => {
        console.log(err.stack + "***");
        process.abort();
    });


    szConfigFilename = "../configWrong.txt";
    let ConfigHandlerObj = new DbConfigHandler();
    try {
        ConfigHandlerObj.load(szConfigFilename);
    } catch (err) {
        if (err instanceof Error) {
            ConfigHandlerObj.load(szConfigFilename);
        } else {
            process.exit(1);
        }
    }

}

// Main starts here
MainAwait();
```

ConfigHandler.js

```
'use strict';

const fs = require('fs')

class ConfigHandler {
    constructor() {
    }

    createCredentialArray(szFileName) {
        try {
            fs.readFileSync(szFileName);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }

    load(szFileName) {
        try {
            this.createCredentialArray(szFileName);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
};

module.exports = ConfigHandler;
```

DbConfigHandler.js

```
const ConfigHandler = require('./ConfigHandler.js');

class DbConfigHandler extends ConfigHandler {
    constructor() {
        super();
    }

};

module.exports = DbConfigHandler;
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason why my program was going to "unhandled rejection" instead of "unhandled exception" is because MainAwait is an async function, meaning it returns a promise. Removing the async keyword causes the flow of execution to go through unhandled exception instead.

The async docs

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function

indicate that if there is an exception thrown from an async function, it will return as a rejected promise. MainAwait is an async function which has an exception thrown from the second load function call. This exception error has no try catch to surround it so it is therefore sent back to the initial call of MainAwait as a promise rejection. (The initial call of MainAwait is missing an await, by the way, for dealing with a Promise.)

Anyway, the promise rejection is not handled, so the code jumps to process.on(unhandledRejection) and executes from there.

I'd have appreciated someone seeing and taking a crack at answering this post, but I've also gained a lot of experience in creating a better mcve. This "mcve" was actually not minimum. Only the async function was needed in one file. Also, I see a lot of value now in searching the documentation instead of waiting for a specific answer from an expert which may never come. Lesson Learned. Hopefully this is useful to someone going forward.